# Npm start deletes new files from .nuxt

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, feathersjs, npm-start

Whenever I run "npm start" it always deletes, and even "reset" files, that I add in my .nuxt folder. As in, when I add, as an example, a new component in the .nuxt > "components" folder, press CTRL + C in cmd to stop the server and then restart running "npm start", it always "resets" the .nuxt folder to its initial/install state. Why is this happening?
I am using "**FeathersJS**" for backend and "**NuxtJS**" for frontend.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "npm run eslint && npm run mocha",
"eslint": "eslint src/. test/. --config .eslintrc.js",
"build": "nuxt build",
"dev": "SET DEBUG=nuxt:* && nodemon --watch src/ --watch config/ src/index.js",
"prestart": "npm run build",
"start": "SET NODE_ENV=production && nodemon src/",
"mocha": "mocha test/ --recursive"
},
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found my own solution now. The solution can be found here, for future reference: https://github.com/fexell/FeathersJS-NuxtJS

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't even add or delete anything from .nuxt. It is files generated by .nuxt. You should modify your sources only, not a generated files.

Comment: Okay? Then how do I add something like a menu component into default? I don't want to have to import the menu component every time I make a new page/view. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin its not the best idea. But if you want you need to put it into plugin https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#vue-plugins